# How can I create a WPF DependencyProperty that inherits the DataContext?

Tags: wpf

I've created a class that has dependency properties that can be specified in xaml. E.g.:

```
public class ToolWindowView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TabTitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TabTitle", typeof(object), typeof(ToolWindowView));
```

This works fine, and I can create controls that derive from ToolWindowView and set the TabTitle.

```
<tw:ToolWindowView x:Class="..." x:ClassModifier="internal"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:tw="clr-namespace:..."
         tw:ToolWindowView.TabTitle="My title">
```

But when I try to create a xaml element with a binding as the value of the DependencyProperty, the DataContext is null and the bindings fail:

```
<tw:ToolWindowView x:Class="..." x:ClassModifier="internal"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:tw="clr-namespace:...">
<tw:ToolWindowView.TabTitle>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
</tw:ToolWindowView.TabTitle>
```

I think I understand the reason is due to the fact that the dependencyproperty isn't part of the logical tree. I can muck around with AddLogicalChild to add the value of DependencyProperty to the logical tree, and sort of get this to work, but it's not obvious when I should be adding the logical children to the tree, or if this is even the right way. It seems much more complicated than it should be. Does anyone know how to do this correctly, or know of a tutorial for this?

Comment: What is `MyText`? Is it a property of an object that is your control's `DataContext`?

Comment: Where do you create a ToolWindowView instance? Does its parent control have its DataContext set, so that it would be inherited by the ToolWindowView? Besides that, the question title is confusing. It's not a dependency property that inherits a DataContext. Instead, it's the DataContext property of a FrameworkElement that inherits a value by [Property Value Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.110).aspx).